# NavigationView Как отоброзить иконку без заливки цвета?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, navigationbar

NavigationView Как отоброзить иконку без заливки цвета? есть xml иконка разноцветная. Вот пример = [image] какой параметр  нужно удалить из дефолт шаблона в а.с.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно гугловому запросу

> [navigation view icon color](https://www.google.ru/search?q=navigation%20view%20icon%20color&oq=%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BC%D1%88%D0%BF%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%89%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D1%88%D1%83%D1%86%20%D1%88%D1%81%D1%89%D1%82&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.7678j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

и ссылке на en-SO - [Navigation drawer item icon not showing original colour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31999206/3212712)

надо так:

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```